# Is Peripheral side implementation is needed at all in real practice

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to CoreBlueTooth, I can understand peripheral side implementation is required when we are using iPhone/iPad device as a BLE device, but I wanted to know if the peripheral implementation will be required at all while communicating with the actual BLE devices like Heart Rate Monitors & Speakers etc.

Please help, suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes its required to use peripheral implementation when you want to achieve something like you said. You can see this link also. https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `CBPeripheralManager` in this case, but you will use `CBPeripheral` objects that are retrieved from your `CBCentralManager`